# How to obtain rotation matrix from point cloud pcd file?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have pcd file that I need to extract the rotation matrix from it.
Is that possible?

Comment: A rotation matrix is just one way to represent a rotation, but's not even clear what rotation you mean. If you have **two** clouds representing the same points using a different basis, those two basis might be related by a rotation or other linear transform, but that's just guessing. You need to tell us your problem, and at this point it's not even clear if it's a programming or a math question.

Comment: My problem is that I want to obtain the orientation of a 3d object but I don't know how to compute the orientation from the transformation matrix 4×4 that I obtained

Comment: Ur question is too vague, add ur problem to the question.